# In task admin, why is CPU% shown as a whole number? (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: gnome-terminal, monitor

When i enter gnome-system-monitor a window pops up with the CPU % that every process is taking, however it just shows a number like 1,2,3,4... not a real percentage. How can I see real percentages?

[image]

Comment: Your application is displaying CPU % as a whole number. For example **Web Content** displays as `0`%. My application displays it as a fraction so it appears as `0.06`% or `0.13`%. However when rounded it would be `0`% as your application displays it. If you want your application to be enhanced you need to put in a feature request to the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome system monitor displays the percentage CPU as a rounded number. For practical purposes, this is more than adequate, and provides you sufficient information as to what is going on. Moreover, this percentage is a snapshot, an averaged measure over a short period of time. In reality, that number changes all the time, so rendering it with a precision of 1% is more than adequate for almost any common purpose.

If, for academic purposes, you want to see the first decimal, `top` (installed by default) and `htop` (not present on a default Ubuntu install) are your friends. I am not sure of methods or applications that would allow to display that number with even greater precision, and where you could customize the time on which the average measurement is done.